# so how many possibilties for 3 random missing words?

Tags: wallet-recovery

I have a combination of 24 words made from 2048 words. I have 21 of these words known and in order. I am missing 3 words that can be placed in any slot from the 24. How can I work out the number of outcomes that I need to try to find these 3 missing words and where they are in the code?

Answer (score 1):

You have 21 words, out of 24. Therefore, 21 of 24 slots are taken, but not necessarily correctly.

There are 2048 possibilities for each word.

The first word can go into one of any 24 positions, therefore 2048*24. The next in any of 23, and the last in any of 22.

This gives you a total of `2048 * 24 * 2048 * 23 * 2048 * 22`, or `2048^3 * 24 * 34 * 22`.

That's a total of 154,206,505,795,584 possible combinations. While not impossible to compute, at a reasonable rate of 100,000 attempts per second, you'll be able to try them all in just under 50 years.

This task is highly parallelizable, so you could likely cut that down significantly if you can obtain enough hardware. Even simply knowing the locations of the missing words cuts down the brute force time at 100k guesses a second to just under a day.

Comment: ok..so here comes the next problem..when im running this program for 2 missing random words its total combinations are 1157627904...

so it works

2048*24*2048*23 = 2315255808

but then looks like it divides them by 2

hence giving 1157627904 total combinations

could it be because once a word is found it deducts the process for teh next words?

Comment: You won't know if one word is found until you find all the words, assuming you have an address or some key you can validate the seed against. Your script might be wrong, or computing some other set of combinations

Comment: im using BTC recover

inserting address correctly

then inserting my 21 words and added anotehr extra word for a total of 22 words

as i start BTC recover it shows

seed sentence was too short, inserting 2 words into each guess

phase 1/1: up to 2 mistakes, 2 of which can be an entirely different seed word

total seeds tried 1157627904

Comment: also when i tried with 3 missing words in 3 definite poistions like 19,20,21 it worked correctly 2048^3

Comment: so the scripts runs well...but i cant just determine the number of total combinations for the 3 random missing words

Comment: My best guess is that it is either attempting to split the word into two halves over multiple CPUs/devices, or it does some kind of optimization that allows it to cut down on attempts with a high probability of not missing the correct solution - hard to say without spending time looking at the code

Comment: or could it be possible that since it works first x 24 then x 23 it divides by 2 as its running the process twice?

Comment: @RaghavSood Since the only relationship between the words is the checksum and the SHA256 hash used in creation of it can not be predicted, there is no way to skip any checks. So the entire 2315255808 permutations must be checked to find the valid ones according to checksum (usually ~6%) then derive child keys for those.